# Value is transformed when loaded into R

Tags: r, csv

I load my data

```
spend <- read.csv("path/spending.csv",sep=";",dec=",",stringsAsFactors =F)
```

in data,  there is column `campaign_id`

```
which(grepl(23843044135350128, spend$campaign_id))
integer(0)
```

But value `23843044135350128` there is in data, when I open it via txt file!!!

But if I open `spending.csv` via excel, value `23843044135350128` in column is absent.
And if I try find it via `ctrl+f`, and I just enter `'128'`, it finds such value

```
23843112895260700
```

This value is in `1400th` row. But ,if open via `.txt`, on `1400th` row is needed for me value.
What's wrong and how load data in R?

Comment: Why `grepl` ? Try `which(spend$campaign_id == 23843044135350128)`

Comment: same integer(0)

Comment: I think you have saved csv file in excel with some changes. do one thing open the csv file in excel and convert it it Number. after that import it to R and later check with  solution provided by ronak . which(spend$campaign_id == 23843044135350128)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your number exceeds the precision allowed by a double floating point number in R. [double precision floating point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), so the number gets rounded when it is converted into numeric.

Example:

```
print(23843044135350130,digits=22)
# [1] 23843044135350128
```

The function `read.csv` initially reads data in as `character` and converts afterwards according to how it thinks the data should be rendered. You can use the argument colClasses (see `?read.table`) to overwrite the default.

```
spend <- read.csv("path/spending.csv",sep=";",dec=",",stringsAsFactors =F,colClasses=c(campaign_id='character'))
```

This will maintain the `campaign_id` column as character, which from the name I would assume is better since IDs are normally used for matching and not for arrithmetic.